# File directorys not working correctly on hosting platforms for website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used WAMPserver to build and test my website. I tried to host on dreamhost and 000webhost and for whatever reason the website is not working properly. When submitting files into the ftp manager if I place all the files sperately html,css,js,php everything works fine for the most part. Half of the pages do not open and none of the pictures work. When submitting the entire folder (The file paths for pictures have the root folder first and will only work with that in there) none of the website works. I can find my index.html page only when i manually put the folder name in and do /index.html.

If everything works on WAMP and also just opening the html file locally woouldnt it work on these hosted servers?

Thanks in advance

Same as above for detals. Website works locally but not on the hosting platforms